# Getting Excel to Auto Increment correctly

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a question regarding Auto Incrementing when dragging formulas.

I have several series of data in columns on a sheet and I am trying to reference them on another sheet.

So on sheet2 I place the following in Cell A2:
='War Participation & AttackTrack'!C1. Based on previous experience, I need to give it a few more entries to know what to do so I add the following 2 lines in A3 and A4: ='War Participation & AttackTrack'!D1 ='War Participation & AttackTrack'!E1

Now I only want just the Column to increment, not the number. When I highlight all 3 cells and drag down, I instead get the following in cell A4: ='War Participation & AttackTrack'!C4

Why am I getting this and how/can I get it to increment properly? The alternative is for me to manually enter quite a few lines or write a macro to do it.

Edit: Adding a more complex example of the same issue for reference:

I have =(SUM('War Participation & AttackTrack'!D2:D1000)/(B3*2)) followed by =(SUM('War Participation & AttackTrack'!E2:E1000)/(B4*2)). I want the columns to increment in the first range and the column and row to increment in the next range. Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of playing around auto-incrementing to work use `OFFSET` or `INDIRECT` functions, e.g.:

`=(SUM(OFFSET('War Participation & AttackTrack'!D2:D1000,0,ROW()-1))/(OFFSET(B3,ROW()-1,0)*2))`

This will shift right your first range and shift down second reference. (place first formula in row 1).